# Implementing some validation... stuck

Tags: c++

Hey I'm trying to add some validation to my program to ensure the correct file is loaded, my validation is based on a dictionary file and I'm trying to implement something that ensures the correct types of words are in the file such as noun and verbs, I've written this...

```
                    if (!type.compare("n") == 0) {
                    cout << "\nType is invalid please check file.\n" << endl;
                    system("Pause");
                }
```

I have an IF statement for each type of word, so one for verb, adverb, adjective and so on, though from the looks of it its checking each type for all the combinations, the difference between each IF statement is what type is comparing for the verb it would be `if (!type.compare("n") == 0)` and so on.

(an example)

```
a
the letter a
n
(blankline)
```

this is the layout, `word`, `definition`, `type` and a `blank` line, from the looks of it it's checking to see is the type matches all the combinations... `n` `v` `adv` and ect... I want to change this so it only searches for either of the combinations. Below is the full function I've stripped it down.

Comment: Don't use `system("pause")` in such a context. Just exit the application.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your comparison due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The expression

```
!type.compare("n") == 0
```

is seen by the compiler as

```
(!type.compare("n")) == 0
```

This means that when `type` is `"n"` then the expression is false, as `!type.compare("n")` is "true", and not equal to zero in any way.

Instead do

```
if (type.compare("n") != 0)
{
    ...
}
else // No need to do `if (type.compare("n") == 0)`
{
    ...
}
```